# How get user's friends using Face Book graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wand to get logged user's all friends and their user ids.I tried with graph api `{friend_list_id}/members` but I got

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

I think this mean there are no any friends for this friend list id.Then I tried with `me/friends` but it doesn't provide all friends.Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use This one me/friendlists but one condition is there.

The field 'friendlists' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'read_custom_friendlists' permission.

Comment: yes it return whole friend-list for the user.but I unable to get friends(members) of the friend-list when I supplied friend-list-id.